Dependence of lossless compression (e.g. Lempel-Ziv) on string length and alphabet size
Suppose we have a lossless compression algorithm A, which compresses a string of length $n$.The symbols in the string are chosen uniformly at random from an alphabet with cardinality $p$. Different initial strings (all of length $n$) will be compressed to a different extent (more uniform strings can be compressed more, etc.). Suppose $$ L_A(n,p)$$ is the  average length of all the compressed strings. So we know $$L_A(1,p) = 1$$ and $$L_A(n,1) = K$$ for some constant $K$. Question: What is
(a) the dependence of $L_A(n,p)$ on $n$ (for fixed $p$)? (b) the dependence of $L_A(n,p)$ on $p$ (for fixed $n$)?
(To be specific: Let A be the LZ77 lossless compression algorithm.)

There is no guarantee that $L_A(1,p)=1$ holds for all lossless compression algorithms.  Normally, that won't be true; normally, most compression algorithms add some overhead.  Also, it's not true that $L_A(n,1)$ is a constant independent of $n$; the length of the output surely must depend on $n$.  So the question looks like it is based on faulty premises.

Regarding your specific questions, surely the dependence of $L_A$ depends on $A$, so I'm not sure what kind of answer your expecting; the question seems too broad.  If you only want an answer for one compression algorithm, please don't put it in a parenthetical at the end -- you should lead with that.  I'm not sure these questions about LZ77 are research-level.  What prevents you from understanding how LZ77 works, and then calculating the answer?
